# Is enabling PHP script execution on HTML document file extensions a security concern?

Tags: php, apache

I am working on a very old and messy site, which doesn't have a CMS, or a database. However, it has a lot of `.htm` and `.php` files. I need to add some PHP code to some of the `.htm` files, but want to leave the URL as is.

Long story short, is there any problem, or security concern, when enabling PHP script execution for `.htm` files globally, via Apache's `.htaccess`?

What could go wrong? Specifically, I am talking about this configuration change in my Apache web server:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, configuring PHP to execute all files (as your title says) is a bad idea, especially if your website has an upload functionality. Someone could simply upload a PHP file with the extension `.jpg` then execute it on your server, and your server is gone.

However, in your case, if users can't upload `.html` or `.htm` files (or `.php`, of course) then there's almost no added security risk.

Comment: thx. users cant upload anything on this site. Its just for looking. What do you mean with "almost" no risk though?

Comment: @user1721135 It's just a way to say two things: A- I'm not a SuperDuper security expert, so there _might_ be _some_ risk, but AFAIK, there isn't any. B- There's nothing 100% secure (I'm sure you already know that)

Comment: I can confirm that I have worked with html and htm files being passed to the PHP parser before.  As long as an attacker can't upload a file with that extension, then there is no more risk than having PHP files processed by PHP.  I believe PHP is actually designed to handle this too as I'm pretty sure that if you process an HTML file with PHP it comes out as HTML but will allow processing of any in-line PHP tags.

Comment: I think you're mostly looking at a performance penalty since you'll be parsing every HTML file instead of just shooting it out to each visitor.  Size of penalty may be small.

Comment: @Adnan: incorrect... There is extra overhead in even looking for the php tags. Every single HTML file will be parsed by PHP to determine whether or not the file contains any php tags. There most certainly will be increased overhead... But the penalty may be very small.....http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137869/is-it-advisable-to-force-your-web-server-to-parse-html-files-for-php-code

Comment: @BrianAdkins Indeed, it appears you're correct. I've removed my comment.